# Local storage limit

Tags: local-storage

I am working on local storage. I had referred few articles on local storage and what I understood it local storage limit is varies from browser to browser.
I have two query regarding this.

1. how to set local storage limit of all browser in JS?
2. IS there any way if we can increase this value for all browser?

Answer (score 2):

`localStorage` max-limits currently vary per browser from:

1. **2MB** (*Android Browser* on Mobile); to
2. **10MB** (*Chrome* & *Firefox* on Mobile and *Chrome*, *Firefox*, *Opera* & *Internet Explorer 9-11* on Desktop).

**Source:** [HTML5 Local Storage Revisited](http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-local-storage-revisited/) (2015/03/12)

In theory, the size of `localStorage` *can* be customised if the user-agent allows it...

... ***but*** it does not appear that any of the browser vendors have opted (at this point) to enable any front-end customisation of their browser's `localStorage` maximum limit.